# Discord bot won't turn on with node

Tags: discord.js

I am new to coding, and was trying to code a discord bot and when I tried to turn it on after using npm main.js I tried to use node ., the bot would not turn on and cmd would not react at all, this is the code I have at this time

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '/'

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('BotMan 2 is online!')    
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(/message.content.startswith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.legnth).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
});

-

client.login('tag(My tag was here I removed it)');
```

Comment: You mean `node main.js`?

Comment: yes, although I think they do the same, but neither worked.

Comment: I found your code is a bit weird to be able to run as it has some syntax errors. Instead of asking you to provide your full code to debug the issue, why don't you have to look at this repo and see if it helps https://github.com/TannerGabriel/discord-bot